# GCM push notification and update cordova controller function

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing a ionic cordova hybrid application. I am using Gcm to enable push notification features in my application. What I want to achieve in Cordova application is when my GCM Push Notification plugin receive message in onMessage() function in GCMIntentService() class. How my onMessage() function in Push Plugin communicate with my cordova controller javascript class? So that I can update my controller class on background.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/. Please check this link. I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: @sur007 What I want to achieve is triggering cordova application run on background to update $scope value in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done by implementing **BroadcastReceiver** in **Android**

when your receiver notification check case

**case 1 :** if chat screen is open call **BroadcastReceiver** to update chat from database in background

**case 2 :** if chat screen is not open then display notification

Comment: @Mehul Gajjar That means I have to build a custom plugin with  BroadcastReceiver and communicate with my cordova apps